# Round float at 2 decimal places down to the 0.05 or 0.1

Tags: ios, objective-c

I have a float and want to round like this:

```
1.31 = 1.30
1.34 = 1.30
1.37 = 1.35
1.39 = 1.35
```

my (wrong)code:

```
float price = 1.3791;
float priceRounded = [[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%.2f",price]floatValue];
```

Comment: Your samples don't match your title. Why isn't 1.39 rounded to 1.40, for example?

Comment: Maybe the title is wrong. The examples are what I want.

Comment: You may wish to update the title to avoid confusion for future readers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try out this

```
float priceRounded = [[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%.2f",floor(price*20)/20]floatValue];
```

Answer (score 2):

You can eliminate the use of `stringWithFormat:` by doing:

```
float princeRounded = (long)(price * 20) / 20.0;
```

This multiples `price` by 20 then takes the integer result of that (round down basically), and then divides that result by 20 ensuring that the result always ends in `.05`, `.1`, `.15`, etc.

Please note that this always rounds down to the 0.05 or 0.1 like you show in your examples. This isn't the same is rounding to the nearest 0.05 or 0.1 as in your title.